# Optimality cut in callback, cplex,python

Tags: python, callback, cplex

I have an optimization model that can be decomposed. The master problem is a MIP and the subproblem is a LP model. I got inspired by the IBM example (bendersatsp) to expand my benders using a callback. The only difference is that I need to add optimality cut rather than feasibility cut. Again using the former posts here I did that. According to [Bender's algorithm](https://orinanobworld.blogspot.ca/2011/10/benders-decomposition-then-and-now.html), for adding optimality cut I need to check the stopping condition as well as optimality. This is if y is optimal and c'y> z, the optimality cut will be added till c'y=z.

My problem is that when I do not consider the stopping condition for some instances I have the optimal solution and the algorithm works well, whereas it could not find the optimal solution in other instances. If I add the stopping condition it cannot find the optimal solution at all. Could you please help me to figure it out. I appreciate that.

Please find some parts of my code regarding a call back and separate function in the following.

```
class BendersLazyConsCallback(LazyConstraintCallback):       

    def__call__(self):       

        v       = self.v
        u       = self.u
        z       = self.z
        T       = self.T
        workerLP = self.workerLP
        boxty = len(u)
        ite=len(z)
        sol1 = []
        sol2 = []
        sol3 = []
        sol1= self.get_values(u);
        for i in range(1, ite+1): 
            sol3.append([]) 
            sol3[i-1]= self.get_values(v[i-1]);
        sol4=0 
        sol4= self.get_values(T);
        # Benders' cut separation 
        if workerLP.separate (sol3, sol1, sol4, v, u, T):
            self.add(constraint = workerLP.cutLhs, sense = "L", rhs = 
                     workerLP.cutRhs) 

def separate(self, vSol,uSol,TSol, v, u, T): 
    ………… 
    ………… 
    cpx.solve() 
    print("v:",v) # v is a continuous decision variable in the master 
     problem 
    print("u:",u) # u is an integer decision variable in the master problem
    print("T:",T) # T is the dummy decision variable added to the master 
     problem and is the z of the model in the link 
    print("w:",w) # w is the c'y of the model in the link 
    violatedCutFound  = False 
    if cpx.solution.get_status() == cpx.solution.status.optimal and (w >T):
       print("optimum")
       cutVarsList  = [] 
       cutCoefsList = []
       for i in items:
           for k in boxtypes: 
               cutVarsList.append(v[i-1][k-1])
       for k in boxtypes:
           cutVarsList.append(u[k-1])
       cutVarsList.extend(T)
       cutCoefsList=d
       cutCoefsList.append(-1)
       cutLhs = cplex.SparsePair(ind = cutVarsList, val = cutCoefsList) 
       self.cutLhs = cutLhs 
       self.cutRhs = cutRhs
       violatedCutFound  = True 
       print("violatedCutFound ")
    return violatedCutFound
```

Comment: This question was cross-posted [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=4c29487e-6aa0-4df8-b6ea-0fbafe76d2e3&ps=25).

Comment: @rkersh, yes I have posted this question in the IBM Forum a few days ago but I did not get any answer. So, I posted here.

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).